# How can I expose a service to other pods in kubernetes?

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-aks

I have a simple service

```
apiVersion: apps/v1 # for versions before 1.9.0 use apps/v1beta2
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-deployment
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 2 # tells deployment to run 2 pods matching the template
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: nginx:1.7.9
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

And here is how my cluster looks like. Pretty simple.

```
$kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME                                READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP           NODE                      NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
my-shell-95cb5df57-cdj4z            1/1     Running   0          23m   10.60.1.32   aks-nodepool-19248108-0   <none>           <none>
nginx-deployment-76bf4969df-58d66   1/1     Running   0          36m   10.60.1.10   aks-nodepool-19248108-0   <none>           <none>
nginx-deployment-76bf4969df-jfkq7   1/1     Running   0          36m   10.60.1.21   aks-nodepool-19248108-0   <none>           <none>
$kubectl get services -o wide
NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE     SELECTOR
internal-ingress   LoadBalancer   10.0.0.194   10.60.1.35    80:30157/TCP   5m28s   app=nginx-deployment
kubernetes         ClusterIP      10.0.0.1     <none>        443/TCP        147m    <none>
```

```
$kubectl get rs -o wide
NAME                          DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE   CONTAINERS   IMAGES        SELECTOR
my-shell-95cb5df57            1         1         1       23m   my-shell     ubuntu        pod-template-hash=95cb5df57,run=my-shell
nginx-deployment-76bf4969df   2         2         2       37m   nginx        nginx:1.7.9   app=nginx,pod-template-hash=76bf4969df
```

I see I have 2 pods wiht my nginx app. I want to be able to send a request from any other new pod to either one of them. If one crashes, I want to still be able to send this request.
In the past I used a load balancer for this. The problem with load balancers is that they open up a public IP and int this specific scenario, I don't want a public IP anymore. I want this service to be invoked by other pods directly, without a public IP.

I tried to use an internal load balancer.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: internal-ingress
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal-subnet: "my-subnet"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 10.60.1.45
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx-deployment
```

The problem is that it does not get an IP in my `10.60.0.0/16` network like it is described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/internal-lb#specify-a-different-subnet
I get this never ending `<pending>`.

```
kubectl get services -o wide
NAME               TYPE           CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE    SELECTOR
internal-ingress   LoadBalancer   10.0.0.230   <pending>     80:30638/TCP   15s    app=nginx-deployment
kubernetes         ClusterIP      10.0.0.1     <none>        443/TCP        136m   <none>
```

What am I missing? How to troubleshoot? Is it even possible to have pod to service communication?

Comment: You need to use a `Service`: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Comment: ...in the default `ClusterIP` mode, which won't make the service visible outside the cluster.

Comment: Do `kubectl describe svc internal-ingress` and you will  know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the message you provide, it seems you want to use a special private IP address which is in the subnet that the same as the AKS cluster use. I think the possible reason is that the special IP address which you want to use is already assigned by the AKS, it means you cannot use it.

**Troubleshooting**

So you need to guide to the Vnet which your AKS cluster used and check if the IP address is already in use. Here is the screenshot:

[image]

**Solution**

Choose an IP address that is not assigned by the AKS from the subnet the AKS used. **Or** do not use a special one, let the AKS assign your load balancer dynamic. Then change your YAML file like below:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: internal-ingress
  annotations:
    service.beta.kubernetes.io/azure-load-balancer-internal: "true"
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  ports:
  - port: 80
  selector:
    app: nginx-deployment
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a ClusterIP Service (the default type) which creates only a cluster-internal IP and no public IP:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
    - port: 80
      targetPort: 80
```

Then you can access the Service (and thus the Pods behind it) from any other Pod in the same namespace by using the Service name as the DNS name:

```sh
curl nginx-service
```

If the Pod from which you want to access the Service is in a different namespace, you have to use the fully qualified domain name of the Service:

```sh
curl nginx-service.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local
```

Comment: I wasn't able to use ClusterIP since it was allocated in a IP range that was not accessible from the pods. I ended up making an internal load balancer LIke in the other answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/59046803/1387563 Thank you for your reply. I might try harder with ClusterIP in the future. Currently the issue is fixed.